# Create javascript function for submit button to return data

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, tinymce

I'm creating a blog on laravel and so far I have the successful js code for posts that contain a title and content. But I'm having some trouble writing the js function for tags.

I would like to do the same for tags but I'm getting errors on everything I try.

```js
    <script src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js?apiKey=fg5tc8gb4rtw6p9n3njd2hi4965rketxda84pbcfs09hb5x2"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/4.6.4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        tinymce.init({
            selector: '.myeditablediv',
            plugins: 'code , save, autoresize , textcolor colorpicker , emoticons, textpattern , wordcount',
            toolbar: 'save , restoredraft , forecolor backcolor, emoticons',
            save_onsavecallback: function () {
                var content = tinymce.activeEditor.getContent();
            console.log(content);
            }
        });

        $(document).on('click', '#SubmitBtn', function () {
            var content = tinymce.activeEditor.getContent();

            var data = {
                'title': $('#title').val(),
                'content': content,
                '_token': '{{csrf_token()}}'
            };
            $.post('/postData', data, function () {
                  console.log(data);
            });
        });

    </script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Create the title</h1>

        <form>

            {{csrf_field()}}

            <label for="title">Click here to edit the title of your post!</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" id="title"/>

            <h1>Create the content</h1>

            <div class="myeditablediv">Click here to edit the content of your post!</div>

        </form>

        <input type="button" name="Submit" id="SubmitBtn" value="Submit"/>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
<script src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js?apiKey=fg5tc8gb4rtw6p9n3njd2hi4965rketxda84pbcfs09hb5x2"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/4.6.4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        tinymce.init({
            selector: '.myeditabletag',  // change this value according to your HTML
            menu: {
                view: {title: 'Edit', items: 'cut, copy, paste'}
            },
            save_onsavecallback: function () {
                var content = tinymce.activeEditor.getContent();
                console.log(content);
            }
        });

        $(document).on('click', '#SubmitBtn', function () {
            var name = tinymce.activeEditor.getContent();

            var data = {
                'name': name,
                '_token': '{{csrf_token()}}'
            };

            $.post('/postTags', data, function () {
                console.log(data);
            });
        });

    </script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Create a new Tag</h1>

        <form>
        {{csrf_field()}}

            {{--<input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>--}}

            <div class="myeditabletag">Click here to edit the name of your tag!</div>

        </form>
        <input type="button" name="Submit" id="SubmitBtn" value="Submit"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the route for /postData for tags and posts:

```
Route::post('/postTags', ['uses' => 'TagController@store']);
Route::post('/postData', ['uses' => 'PostController@store']);
```

And here is the PostController and TagController store method:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $post = new Post;
    $post->title = $request['title'];
    $post->content = $request['content'];
    $post->save();
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $tag = new Tag;
    $tag->name = $request['name'];
    $tag->save();
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: I changed $.post to $.tag and it says $.tag is not a function. Also I changed title into name of the tag. Even if I do that, it still doesn't return any data on my phpmyadmin like it does with posts.

Comment: Yea because jquery doesn't offer a method that is called `$.tag`? I am confused that confuses you.

Comment: @Xatenev I'm sorry I'm new on this so don't judge me. I still get errors on the variables I've used.

Comment: At the moment there's not enough information to understand exactly what's going wrong. Can you post the errors that the console is displaying to you?

Comment: Can you share with us the code where you are getting that `tag` I'd, the route (/postData) and the controller that it's pointing to, in addition to the errors you're getting?

Comment: @yahyazini I just edited my post. Take a look

Comment: But *what is* `#tag` ?

Comment: @livia you have 2 duplicate routes, are those under the same route group?

Comment: @AndyHolmes maybe I should put name instead of tag. On the tag table I have $table->string('name'). I'm not very clear.

Comment: @yahyazini no they're on different routes. I mean on routes I created the routes for tags in: 
Route::resource('/tags', 'TagController');
and the routes for posts in: 
Route::resource('/posts', 'PostController');

Comment: Okay so here's one issue you have. You're telling the script to get the value of `#tag` to populate your `tag` in the POST, however, the console.log returns `tag:undefined` - that's something that needs addressing, hence my question :) @livia

Comment: @Andy Holmes is right. Can you make sure you have an input with the I'd of tag? And add the HTML to the question just so we can better help you?

Comment: @yahyazini the first two belong to post.blade.php and the second two to tag.blade.php

Comment: When you are posting that #tag value means that you need an input with an I'd of tag like so: <input id="tag" type=text"/> Therese the JavaScript code cannot find the values of #tag resulting in that undefind value. I don't see that input anywhere in your code.

Comment: @yahyazini that's because when I put <input id="tag" etc it returns two editors, the small tag editor and the big tinymce editor. I only need that one tinymce editor for tag's name so I can relate it with posts. How can I modify the form in order for the user to create a tag?

Comment: ID's need to be unique

Comment: @yahyazini I tried the edit you suggested, it still doesn't work

Comment: The edits I suggested are just to offer some more clarity to people who come here to help. There were errors in the code and I also added a tinymce tag!

Comment: @yahyazini yes I noticed, thank you very much. But when you suggest your edit, I change my code to the one you suggest and it doesn't work. But feel free to tell me more and edit my post, you obviously know more than me in this case :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake in your JS code. You are selecting an ID that doesn't exist. You need to select the content of the changed tag, and send that as the data['name']. Try the following code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/4.6.4/tinymce.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector: '.myeditabletag',  // change this value according to your HTML
        menu: {
            view: {title: 'Edit', items: 'cut, copy, paste'}
        },
        save_onsavecallback: function () {
            var content = tinymce.activeEditor.getContent();
            console.log(content);
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#SubmitBtn', function () {
        var name = tinymce.activeEditor.getContent();

        var data = {
            'name': name,
            '_token': '{{csrf_token()}}'
        };

        console.log(data);
        $.post('/postTags', data, function () {

        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Could you add more details to your post? Error messages etc, so that we can troubleshoot?

Comment: I'm watching the errors on console. I believe it is the var data

POST http://blog.app/postData 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
r.(anonymous function) @ jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ tag:29
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
q.handle @ jquery.min.js:3

Comment: have you tried doing `console.log(data);` before the $.post call so you can see what's being sent?

Comment: @AndyHolmes
It says
tag:undefined

Comment: There you go then @livia

Comment: @livia could you inspect the page, and copy the code generated by tinymce for the input form, as we need to know which code is generated by the plugin.

Comment: @ImerMuhović
Navigated to http://blog.app/tag
tag:29 Object {tag: "", content: "<p>This is a tag</p>", 
_token: "kvv3UZLmIT7wrirqagECNUCp4BDrjeq8Eh7tGuPP"}
jquery.min.js:4 POST http://blog.app/postData 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
r.(anonymous function) @ jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ tag:30
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
q.handle @ jquery.min.js:3

Comment: The problem you are facing is this: Your code works in the first scenario you pasted because it has an <input> element with the id="title" attribute. It breaks in the second scenario because on the website there doesn't exist an HTML element with the id="tag" attribute.

Comment: @livia try the code I just updated. I'll write up a more detailed explanation as to why it was failing, but should work now.

Comment: @ImerMuhović should I leave the rest of the code as it is?

Comment: @livia You would also need to make sure that you are posting to the correct route. As in your original question i see you were posting both tags and posts to the same same route, so change $.post('/postData', data, function () ) to match the route path you are posting to.

Comment: @ImerMuhović IT WORKED, thank you so so much. I don't know what else to say. The new tag is stored in  the database. Thank you a lot Imer :) :) :)

Comment: No problem. Please mark the question as answered, and change the routes in the original question to the current ones, as they were not the root cause of your issue.